# C++ static library - how to create .a file from .lib?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I downloaded an opensource C++ library. The problem is that it's a library object file (`.lib`).  This is how it is distributed. On the other hand I am trying to use it as a static library using `Android NDK` and this expects a `.a` file. Its been years since I've used C++ so perhaps someone could clarify this. Not really sure why they distribute as `.lib` vs. `.a` file? And how can I create `.a` file from the `.lib` one?

Comment: please add tags as appropriate

Comment: It's open source, right? Why don't you grab the source and build a `.a` object yourself?

Comment: the source is available. not too familiar with make files.

Comment: @Androider: If you're going to be writing Android apps, then I suggest you become familiar with Makefiles and other GNU-based building tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the `ar` command from binutils:

```
ar rcs mylib.a mylib.lib
```

Comment: I'm on cygwin.  I've got ar.  ar c mylib.a mylib.lib yields no operation specified.

Comment: ah... if you're on cygwin, I must warn: the .lib might be an `import library` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries). However, I've update my command with the correct switches, sry for memory failure